# form in php and submit button?

Tags: php, html, forms, xhtml, webforms

I have the form and the php, the form asks the user what he would like to buy and the user selects and it adds it up, i want it so that when the submit button is clicked, the data that is stored in the php vairables are shown below the submit button but i dont know how to do that!

```
    <p><b>Billing Information</b></p>
    <form action="" method="get">

        <p>Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
      <strong>Items:</strong></p>
    </form>
  <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="one" value= "2.39"/> 
        <label for="one">Four 100-watt light bulbs for $2.39</label>
      <p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="two" value= "4.29"/> 
  <label for="two">Eight 100-watt light bulbs for $4.29</label>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="three" value= "3.95"/> 
  <label for="three">Four 100-watt long-life light bulbs for $3.95</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="four" value= "7.49"/> 
  <label for="four">Eight 100-watt long-life light bulbs for $7.49</label>
    </p>
            <input name="battery" name = "battery" type="number" id="battery" size="1" maxlength="3" />
<label for="battery">Battery Packs Checkbox $10.42 each:</label>
         </p>
      <p><strong><b>Card  Details</b>:</strong></p>
<p>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['value']))
    {
        $one = $_POST['one'];
        $two = $_POST['two'];
        $three = $_POST['three'];
        $four = $_POST['four'];
        $five = $_POST['battery'];

    $total = $one + $two + $three + $four + $battery;
    $interest  = $total * 0.175;
    echo "Total cost is " .$total; 
    }
    ?>
    </p>
      <p>
        <p>
    <input name="Visa" type="radio" value= <?php $cardone = "Visa"; ?>
     <p>Visa</p>
    <p>
          <input name="Mastercard" type="radio" value= <?php $cardtwo = "Mastercard"; ?> 
        <p>Mastercard</p>
    <p>
          <input name="American" type="radio" value=<?php $cardthree = "American Express"; ?> 
         <p> American Express    </p>
<p>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['value']))
    {
        $cardone = $_POST['cardone'];
        $cardtwo = $_POST['cardtwo'];
        $cardthree = $_POST['cardthree'];
    $total = $cardone + $cardtwo + $cardthree;
    echo "You have chose to pay using a " .$total; 
    }
    ?>
<input type="Submit" name="SubmitForm" value="Submit">
<form action="Results.php" method="post">
<input name="Submit" type="button" />
</p>
</form>
```

I'm sorry if this didnt come out ok but the HTML thing is not very good. please help me!

Comment: You have to submit the form into a new page you can't get the `$_POST` from a value on the same page.

Comment: What is `$_POST['cardone']? There's no form field with that name, the name is `Mastercard`. And why are you adding these fields, they're not numbers?

Comment: For one thing, you have `<input type="Submit" name="SubmitForm" value="Submit">` OUTSIDE your `<form...`

Comment: @believeme Of course you can, you just have to check whether the form was submitted, by checking whether the submit input is set.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking the very same thing.

Comment: And what's `$_POST['value']`, there's no input with that name, either. It seems like that should be `$_POST['Submit']`.

Comment: but how do you send the values from the first php page to the next one?

Comment: im adding them because if they are clicked then it will add them otherwise from what i understand it wont do anything, but i only want the one that is clicked, how do i do that?

Comment: Radio buttons for credit cards should be something similar to this: `<?php $creditcard = "Visa"; ?>` - `<?php $creditcard = "Mastercard"; ?>` - `<?php $creditcard = "American_Express"; ?>` Since it's a radio button, the initial name should be the same but not the value.

Comment: ok so i took all the php out and put it in a seperate file so that it will get the data and then do stuff with it when the submit button is clicked, how do i make the submit button load the php file? thanks for your help people

Comment: @user2174315 All form elements MUST reside inside `<form.....></form>` - You presently have your Submit button outside it.

Comment: You have been editing your code quite often. I am not sure what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no form field 'value' and you didnt close the form. Also, there is no $battery
The below solution works for me

```
   <p><b>Billing Information</b></p>
    <form action="" method="get">

        <p>Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
      <strong>Items:</strong></p>
    </form>
  <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="one" value= "2.39"/> 
        <label for="one">Four 100-watt light bulbs for $2.39</label>
      <p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="two" value= "4.29"/> 
  <label for="two">Eight 100-watt light bulbs for $4.29</label>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="three" value= "3.95"/> 
  <label for="three">Four 100-watt long-life light bulbs for $3.95</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="four" value= "7.49"/> 
  <label for="four">Eight 100-watt long-life light bulbs for $7.49</label>
    </p>


            <input name="battery" name = "battery" type="number" id="battery" size="1" maxlength="3" />
<label for="battery">Battery Packs Checkbox $10.42 each:</label>

    <input type ="submit" name="value" />

</form>
      <p><strong><b>Card  Details</b>:</strong></p>



<p>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['value']))
    {
        $one = $_POST['one'];
        $two = $_POST['two'];
        $three = $_POST['three'];
        $four = $_POST['four'];
        $five = $_POST['battery'];

    $total = $one + $two + $three + $four + $five;

    $interest  = $total * 0.175;
    echo "Total cost is " .$total; 
    }


    ?>

    </p>
```

EDIT: I dont know if you need 'Name' in a separate form. I might be wrong about that though.
EDIT: You have changed your code quite a bit in your question. Not Sure if this answer is applicable anymore.